# Searching on main for a word but not its tag

Tags: support, tags, search

Here in meta, when I type in the word `calculus` (for example) in the search bar at the top of the page (the one with the prompt `Search on Mathematics Educators Meta...`), I am shown a list of posts having that word.

However, in main, when I type in the word `calculus` in the search box, my search term is changed to `[calculus]` and I am shown a list of posts having the tag [calculus](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculus).

This is a problem because I was looking for posts having the word `calculus` but not necessarily having the tag [calculus](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculus).

In the end, I just typed `[calculus` in the search box.  (`calculus]` won't work.)

> Is there an easier way to search for a word but not its tag?

Comment: Post about the same problem on Meta Stack Exchange: [Why are search queries inconsistently converted into tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146311)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search for "calculus" *with* the quotes.

As with other search facilities a string under quotes will result in search for an exact match. For a single word it does not change anything but will prevent conversion into a tag.